# What is the rank of matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ with entries $a_{i,j} = i + j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I've been sitting on this practice question for a while but haven't been able to make any progress. Thanks in advance for any help.

Below is an $n \times m$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$:

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}& \dots &a_{1,n}\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
a_{m,1}&...&a_{m,n}\end{bmatrix} \text{with} \ a_{i,j} = i + j  \ \text{for all} \ i \in {1,..m}, \  j\in{1,...n}.$$

Determine the row and column rank of the matrix $A$ for any $n,m > 0$.

How do I go about this question?
I know the rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent rows or columns, but I don't really know how to apply that to this matrix.

P.S: please excuse my poor formatting.

Comment: Hint: the matrix does have number entries: $i$ and $j$ are always numbers. Write down the matrix for some small values of $n,m$ and compute their ranks explicitly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say that the matrix has "non-number entries".  For instance, in the $3 \times 3$ case, we have
$$
A =  \pmatrix{2&3&4\\3&4&5\\4&5&6}
$$

Comment: I think I am to determine the rank for any matrix of the form, not for specific entries..That's what I mean.

Comment: Suppose that $V_i$ denote the $i$th row of matrix $A$, then
all the rows of matrix $A$ are spanned by vectors 
$V_1=\langle2,3,4,\ldots,n+1\rangle$
and
$
U=\langle1,1,1\ldots,1\rangle.
$
because we have $V_i=V_1+iU$.

It is clear that $\dim (V_1,U)=2$, so the rank of matrix $A$ is $2$. This is the nice answer of user @Jyrki to [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317712/the-vectors-langle-1i-2i-dots-n-1i-ni-rangle-for-0-leq-i-leq-n-1-are/2317757#2317757)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Subtracting any two consecutive rows gives you the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$. Conclude that the rank of the matrix is at most $2$.